# Board game in c++ using qt

Tags: c++, qt

I  have been working on a board game in c++ using qt. The game cosist of four palyer with four different colors. I am looking forward to improving my board looking.

This is all working fine, but I want to know if there is any other way to do this?

["**Readable online**" The code for this part.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByjbQDEh-nyvcEpKZDZ0YzhyWjQ)

```
  std::vector<std::pair<char,char> > directions{std::make_pair(1,-1),std::make_pair(1,1),std::make_pair(-1,1),std::make_pair(-1,-1) };
    for(size_t d =0; d < directions.size(); ++d){
        for(int i=0; i<5;++i){
            if(d % 2 == 0)
                x_pos += directions[d].first * offset;
            else
                y_pos += directions[d].second * offset;
            fieldPos.push_back(QPointF(x_pos,y_pos));
        }
        x_pos += directions[d].first * small_offset;
        y_pos += directions[d].second * small_offset;
        for(int i=0; i<5;++i){
            fieldPos.push_back(QPointF(x_pos,y_pos));
            if(d % 2 == 0)
                y_pos += directions[d].second * offset;
            else
                x_pos += directions[d].first * offset;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<2;++i){
            fieldPos.push_back(QPointF(x_pos,y_pos));
            if(d % 2 == 0)
                x_pos += directions[d].first * large_offset;
            else
                y_pos += directions[d].second * large_offset;
        }
        fieldPos.push_back(QPointF(x_pos,y_pos));
    }
```

I also wonder how to get my board to look like the (rounded )one on the right. That would be very big help for me :)

[image]

Comment: Did you fix the problems mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45779304/1014587)?

Comment: Yes this is different

Comment: @Carcigenicate No not at all

Comment: Could you describe what it is this code is supposed to do? Other than pushing some points into a `vector`, it's not obvious what the significance of the various loops is.

Comment: @user1118321 i wanted to get my code reviewed in general. this part of my code handles the small circles, so that they goe around the corss. I wanted to get them if its posiible to go around a big rounded  ellipse as shown at the end of the post. You may check my full code from readable online

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment, it's not entirely clear what the purpose of this code is, beyond adding points to a `vector`. Given that, I see several things that I think could make this more clear.

## Use Types

C++ is a strongly typed language and that not only gives you type safety, it also improves comprehension. The ultimate goal of this code appears to be to add several `QPointf`s to an array. But it's written with 3 different types to accomplish that job - whatever type `x_pos` and `y_pos` are (presumably `float` or `double`?), `char`s in the `directions` `vector`, and `QPointf` in the `fieldPos` `vector`. This is inefficient as the compiler will end up inserting a bunch of code to convert between types, but more importantly, it obscures what's happening.

I would declare `directions` like this:

```
std::vector<QPointf> directions { 
    QPointf( 1.0, -1.0), 
    QPointf( 1.0,  1.0), 
    QPointf(-1.0,  1.0), 
    QPointf(-1.0, -1.0) 
};
```

I would change `x_pos` and `y_pos` into a single `QPointf`. It implements [`operator+=()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpointf.html#operator-2b-eq) so you can work in a similar manner as you are currently.

In general, when you find yourself using `std::pair`, it's a good sign that you need to use a better type like some sort of point, (mathematical) vector, or size `struct`. Code that uses `std::pair` is very difficult to read because the members, `first` and `second` are meaningless names for whatever task your code is performing.

## Put the Right Things Into the Array

It might be more clear to just make a longer array with the directions you actually want instead of all the various loops. For example, instead of cramming everything into 4 `QPointf`s and looping over them and flipping back and forth between x and y positions, just make the array have what you want in it:

```
std::vector<QPointf> directions { 
    QPointf( 1.0,  0.0), 
    QPointf( 0.0, -1.0), 
    QPointf( 1.0,  0.0), 
    QPointf( 0.0, -1.0),
    // etc.
};
```

This will eliminate the need for multiple loops and the need to check even or odd iterations, which allows you to do the following.

## Use Range-based Looping

Rather than writing a loop based on the size of the `directions` array and then having magic numbers like `5` in your inner loops, you can use the new C++11 and later syntax for [range-based looping](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
for (auto nextPoint : directions)
{
    pos += nextPoint * offset;
    fieldPos.push_back(pos);
}
```

But of course, you're not multiplying them all by `offset`. So your `vector` may need to contain objects of a new type in it that's something like:

```
typedef struct Direction {
    QPointf direction;
    float offset;
} Direction;
```

I'd use better names than `Direction` and `direction`, but since I don't know what they represent, I can't. If it's for a player, then `PlayerDirection`, or whatever's appropriate. So the loop would be more like:

```
for (auto nextDir : directions)
{
    pos += nextPoint.direction * nextPoint.offset;
    fieldPos.push_back(pos);
}
```

It means you'll end up having a long declaration for the array, but it will make the code a lot simpler. You could even put the values into a data file and read them at runtime if you think they'll change in the future.